# Bootstrap form margin not correct at smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this form in the middle:
[image]

I managed to put the form under the logo, in the middle, when I added a style attribute:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" style="margin-left: 170px;">
```

But when I entered and saw the screen on a mobile (Iphone 6 Plus - Developer mode), the form was off, way to much to the right):

[image]

**How do I put the style margin only for big screens ?** 
Mobile and other smaller devices should not like picture 2.

Comment: You tagged `twitter-bootstrap`. So do you really use it or not? If you use it you must not set an margin like this because you could use bootstrap classes to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to remove inline style for HTML code and add class "`mr170`"

```
<form class="form-horizontal mr170">
```

"`form-horizontal`" is a bootstrap call so don't apply css/style on it. it's effect all over project.

Add blow code in css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .mr170 {
      margin-left: 170px;
   }
}
```

**Note:** `mr170` is just random class name whatever name you think use in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you can set media query for margin only for big screens (adjust the px when u need to add margin was added)

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
   .form-horizontal {
      margin-left: 170px;
   }
}
```